# How to implement infinite scrolling in blueprintjs table

Tags: reactjs, blueprintjs

Has anyone  implemented infinite scrolling in BlueprintJS table ? 

 My requirement is to fetch the table date from an api as the user scrolls the table.I have tried with `onCompleteRender` props of BlueprintJS table but it does not meet my requirement as all pages  are fetched in a single go.

 What i have tried is

```
  <div>
                {this.props.spiders.spiders.length !==0 ?
                <Table numRows={this.props.spiders.spiders.length} defaultRowHeight={45} defaultColumnWidth={180} className="bp3-dark tableheight" onCompleteRender={this.scroll} enableRowHeader={false}>
                    <Column name="Name" cellRenderer={cellRenderer} />
                    <Column name="Developer" cellRenderer={cellRenderer}  />
                    <Column name="Status"  cellRenderer={cellRenderer} />
                    <Column name="Workers" cellRenderer={cellRenderer}  />
                    <Column name="Customer"  cellRenderer={cellRenderer} />
                    <Column name="Last Run"  cellRenderer={cellRenderer} />
                    <Column name="Proxy" cellRenderer={cellRenderer}  />
                </Table> :''}
  </div>
```

My `scroll` method is

```
scroll = () =>{
       if(this.props.spiders.next!=null)
       {
           this.props.spiders.page = this.props.spiders.page + 1;
           this.props.pagination()

       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the `onWheel` event to listen for scroll events, then check if we're near the bottom of the element to load the next page.It can be implemented as

```
  <div className="spiderList" id="spidertable" onWheel={this.scrolling} ref="spiders" >
                {this.props.spiders.spiders.length !== 0 ?
                    <Table className="bp3-dark" numRows={this.props.spiders.spiders.length} defaultRowHeight={45} defaultColumnWidth={180} enableRowHeader={false} >
                        <Column name="Name" cellRenderer={cellRenderer} />
                        <Column name="Developer" cellRenderer={cellRenderer} />
                        <Column name="Status" cellRenderer={cellRenderer} />
                        <Column name="Workers" cellRenderer={cellRenderer} />
                        <Column name="Customer" cellRenderer={cellRenderer} />
                        <Column name="Last Run" cellRenderer={cellRenderer} />
                        <Column name="Proxy" cellRenderer={cellRenderer} />
                    </Table> : ''}
            </div>
```

The scroll handler need to check whether the bottom of the `div` has reached ,this can be done using

```
 scrolling() {
        const table = document.getElementById('spidertable')
        if (this.isBottom(table)) {
            if (this.props.spiders.next != null && this.props.loading === false) {
                this.props.spiders.page = this.props.spiders.page + 1;
                //call the api to fetch more table pages
            }
        }
    }
```

We can detect whether users has scrolled to the bottom of the table using the following method

```
 isBottom(el) {
        return el.getBoundingClientRect().bottom <= window.innerHeight;
    }
```